# wget Python package downloads/saves XML without issue, but not text or html files

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, urllib, wget

Have been using this basic code to download and store updated sitemaps from a hosting/crawling service, and it works fine for all the XML files. However, the text and HTML files appear to be in the wrong encoding, but when I force them all to a single encoding (UTF-8) there is no change and the files are still unreadable (screenshots attached). **No matter which encoding is used, the TXT and HTML files are unreadable, but the XML files are fine.**

I'm using Python 3.10, Django 3.0.9, and the latest wget python package available (3.2) on Windows 11. I've also tried using urllib and other packages with the same results.

The code:

```
sitemaps = ["https://.../sitemap.xml",
        "https://.../sitemap_images.xml",
        "https://.../sitemap_video.xml",
        "https://.../sitemap_mobile.xml",
        "https://.../sitemap.html",
        "https://.../urllist.txt",
        "https://.../ror.xml"]

def download_and_save(url):
    save_dir = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    full_path = os.path.join(save_dir, filename)
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)
    wget.download(url, full_path)

for url in sitemaps:
    download_and_save(url)
```

For **all** of the XML files, I get this (which is the correct result):
[image: image of downloaded xml file using WGET]

For the ***urllist.txt*** and ***sitemap.html*** files, however, this is the result:

[image: screenshot of HTML encoding from wget]

I'm not sure why the XML files save fine, but the encoding is messed up for text (.txt) and html files only.

Comment: Tried to reproduce this and was not able to. Using Python 3.10 / wget 3.2 on Linux. I downloaded a sitemap.xml file and then a robots.txt file, and it all worked fine. Have you tried isolating the wget command, like by running `wget.download('https://disney.com/robots.txt', 'disney-robots.txt')` from the Python shell?

Comment: Ill try that and see what happens. Haven't done it yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the sitemap hosting provider (pro-sitemaps.net) it appears that the problem was on their end. The HTML and TXT files I was downloading were being served with the wrong encoding (or something similar to that). Though these files were visible/accessible in the browser from the direct URLs at their service, they were not being served via wget with the right encoding it appears.

I submitted a ticket to the provider and the issue was resolved within 12 hours (though I didn't get confirmation of the exact issue that caused my problem here). I have now verified that the TXT and HTML files are being served by them in the correct encoding/format via wget.